# I have a ftp client installed in ubuntu, how to open port 21?

Tags: php, security, ftp-client, filezilla

I installed FileZilla in windows 7, and want to transfer compressed files from ubuntu (PHP web server) to windows 7 ftp server. How should I open port 21 in ubuntu? Any security issues are very welcomed.

Thanks,

YH

Comment: This question would be better suited to Ask Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running 'netstat -an | grep 21' in a terminal to see if it's listening or not on the server. FTP sends out usernames and passwords unencrypted, so you might wanna look into using SFTP.

Comment: port 21 is not open in ubuntu. Can I install FileZilla client in ubuntu? Filezilla also provides command line, right? Thanks.

Comment: If you're planning on setting up the FTP server on Ubuntu take a look at [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-an-FTP-Server-in-Ubuntu-Linux). If you're unsure on how to use the terminal, here's a quick [guide](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/100) for that too. I hope this helps!

Comment: Also, if the port isn't open it may need to be forwarded from the router.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean to forward it from router?

Comment: Sometimes a port will need to be forwarded from the router (take a look at port forwarding), or perhaps port 21 is already pointing to something else on the network?